# Grid Item wont fit in CSS Grid, although there is enough space for that

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a grid system in which the first part (one to five) is opposite to the second part (six to ten). I managed to make the first one fine but the last part, specifically the tenth piece wont want to fit into the grid... I tried setting the grid row for that as well but had no success! Any possible help with that?

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: rgba(233 171 88 / 0.5);
  color: #d9480f;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
/*   grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr); */
  gap: 5px;
}


.one {
 grid-row: auto / span 6
}

.three {
 grid-row: 7 / span 6
}

.one, .three {
 grid-column: auto / span 6;
}

.two {
 grid-column: auto / span 8;
 grid-row: auto / span 8
}

.four, .five {
 grid-row: 9 / span 4;
 grid-column: auto / span 4
}

.six {
 grid-column: auto / span 8;
 grid-row: auto / span 8;
}

.seven {
  grid-row: auto / span 6;
}

.ten {

}

.seven, .ten {
  grid-column: 9 / span 6;
}

.eight {
 grid-column: 1 / span 4
}

.nine {
 grid-column: 5 / span 4
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">six</div>
  <div class="seven">seven</div>
  <div class="eight">eight</div>
  <div class="nine">nine</div>
  <div class="ten">ten</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check the `grid-auto-flow` `dense` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

Comment: .ten {  grid-row: 19 /span 9;  }

Comment: @StevenXXCCC i combined your answer with Arieljuod and it worked, thanks! Still wondering why span 9 worked in this case

Comment: one comment though, from your image and CSS, looks like grid named areas are a better fit for you? not sure what's the desired end result though

Comment: @arieljuod that's how I want that

Answer (score 0):

With a grid setup as complex as this you’re probably better off drawing it out on paper first, then when writing your CSS, specify the row and column (and associated spans) for every box yourself, rather than relying on `auto` for anything.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: rgba(233 171 88 / 0.5);
  color: #d9480f;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
/*   grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr); */
  gap: 5px;
}


.one {
 grid-row: auto / span 6
}

.three {
 grid-row: 7 / span 6
}

.one, .three {
 grid-column: auto / span 6;
}

.two {
 grid-column: auto / span 8;
 grid-row: auto / span 8
}

.four, .five {
 grid-row: 9 / span 4;
 grid-column: auto / span 4
}

.six {
 grid-column: auto / span 8;
 grid-row: auto / span 8;
}

.seven {
  grid-row: auto / span 6;
}

.ten {
  grid-row: 19 / span 3;
}

.seven, .ten {
  grid-column: 9 / span 6;
}

.eight {
 grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}

.nine {
 grid-column: 5 / span 4;
}

.eight, .nine {
 grid-row: 21;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">six</div>
  <div class="seven">seven</div>
  <div class="eight">eight</div>
  <div class="nine">nine</div>
  <div class="ten">ten</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually wanted to leave all grid-rows on auto (the code that I published isnt like this but I managed to have all of them on auto) because that is a pattern that will be replicated through css class alternation by using nth-child(n...)... thanks for you answer!